# presentViewController shows white screen 10-15 second

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
ChangePasswordPage *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"changedPass5"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If I put this code in `viewDidLoad` it will work, but when I run it in a function, it still works, but after 10-15 seconds with a white screen and then the screen loads correctly.

Why is that?

Here is some related code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("x.x", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    while(true)
    {
        sleep(1);
        checkCacheForRefreshDone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"homeScreenRefreshDone"];
        userChangedPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userChangedPassword"];


       if ([checkCacheForRefreshDone isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            [self installAfterRefresh];    
            [feedHomeTable reloadData];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"homeScreenRefreshDone"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            checkCacheForRefreshDone = @"0";
            [refresh endRefreshing];
            break;
        }

    }

});


-(void)installAfterRefresh
{

    userChangedPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userChangedPassword"];

    if ([userChangedPassword isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        [self detectPhone];
    }
}
```

`detectPhone` function of using presentViewController

FIX :
Add this method:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(detectPhone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: Probably you're not doing it on the main thread. What function are you calling it in, and what calls _that_ function?

Comment: Yes ,i use `dispatch_async`

Comment: That's probably it then. Can you update the question with that code?

Comment: Then you may not be aware that all UIKit code must be run on the main thread. It is not safe to execute on any other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write your code without self.storyboard.

Change:

```
ChangePasswordPage *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"changedPass5"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To be:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ChangePasswordPage *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"changedPass5"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method from a background thread. All calls affecting the UI must be done on the main thread - a long delay before an animation or presentation is a telltale sign that a method is on the wrong thread.

Use `dispatch_async` to call the code back onto the main thread.